# RavenDB return IDynamicJsonObject Or RavenJObject

Tags: ravendb

I am using RavenDb with the latest client and also for server side. It's really weird that when I use Load(string id), for the first time, it returns a RavenJObject. But with the same id, the second time, it returns a IDynamicJobject.

Can someone help me to explain it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are likely creating the docs manually, so they don't have the `Raven-Clr-Type` metadata value.

Because of that, we don't know what the type is, and use dynamic, since you didn't provide a type for us.

The 2nd time, we already had a type, and you saved it, so we have the type metadata and we can infer what the type is.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for your comments.